# JavaFX graphic glitch (white boxes)

Tags: user-interface, javafx, progress-bar, visual-glitch

I experienced a graphic glitch developing a JavaFX application.

*Here is how it should look:*
[image]
*Here is the glitch:*

### [image]

**At first the context ...**
After button "Ausführen" (Execute) is pressed a second thread starts doing something and a progress bar shows the current progress. When the thread is working you can cancel it pressing button "Abbrechen". The thread takes a few seconds to terminate, thus I want set the progress bar to indeterminate until the thread is terminated.

**Reproducing the glitch ...**
I guess, the indeterminate progress bar is the source of the problem, because I can't reproduce the glitch without it. 
The glitch occurs after multiple times (about 10 times) toggling the progress bar between indeterminate and not indeterminate. Additionally resizing the window leads to the glitch.

All controls still work with the glitch and  resizing the window again removes the white boxes and everything looks normal. However the glitch will appear again when toggling the progress bar between indeterminate and not indeterminate.

Has anyone experienced something similar and can provide a solution?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. I had to remove the progress bars and find an other solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled across the same issue (and without any progress bars). It seems to be [JDK-8089308](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8089308). Providing `-Dprism.dirtyopts=false` to Java fixes the issue. Changing this option with `System.setProperty()` doesn't work for some reason.

A related article that helped to track down the bug: http://werner.yellowcouch.org/log/javafx-8-command-line-options/